# Find strings with maximum vowels

Tags: python

I want to find strings with maximum vowels in Python, but I don't know how.

#### Examples

Input

```
['Zak6aa','kak','ll','ak']
```

Output:

```
['Zak6aa']
```

Another if two or more strings tie for max vowels:

```
['Zaa', 'bii','ak']
```

output is:

```
['Zaa', 'bii']
```

My try:

```
def maxv(string):
    sam=0
    seq=[]
    for i in range(len(string)):
        k=0
        v=0
        for char in string[i]:
             if char in "aeiouy":
                v = v+1
        k=(len(string[i]))-v
        if (v >=k):
            seq=seq+[string[i]]
    return seq
```

Comment: How are you calling your function? What happens? You can try printing the variables in the function to understand what's going on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One Solution using loops.

```
l=['Zak6aa','kak','ll','ak']
L={}
for x in l:
  cnt=x.count('a')+x.count('e')+x.count('i')+x.count('e')+x.count('u')
  if cnt not in L.keys():
    L[cnt]=[]
  L[cnt].append(x)
print(L[max(L.keys())])
```

You can count the number of occurrences of vowels using `re`

```
import re
cnt=len(re.findall(r'[aeiou]{1}',x))
```

Comment: Or just do `if cnt not in L`

Comment: Yes. That would be enough.

Answer (score 0):

You can `sort` them by the number of vowels:

```
l = ['Zak6aa','kak','ll','ak']
sorted(l, key=lambda x: sum(1 for y in x if y in 'aeiouAEIOU'), reverse=True)
['Zak6aa', 'kak', 'ak', 'll']
```

If you need all with the same max lenght, you can use zip with the number of vowels before sorting and then just filter the higher "scores":

```
l = ['Zaa', 'bii','ak']
slist =sorted(zip(map(lambda x: sum(1 for y in x if y in 'aeiouAEIOU'), l), l), reverse=True)
filter(lambda x: x[0] == slist[0][0], slist)
[(2, 'bii'), (2, 'Zaa')]
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everybody

How to print the number of swaps in selection sort in Python?
For example 
output `

> [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 9, 8]

`
input

> 1

because there is 1 swap 9 with 8.

```
  def min(list, fromw):
      m = fromw
      for i in range(fromw + 1,len(list)):
          if list[i] < list[m]:
              m = i
      return m


def select(list):
    for promt in range(len(list)):
        where = min(list, promt)
        list[where], list[promt] = list[promt], list[where]
    return list
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried to solve this with lower complexity:

```
sample_string="i am a sample string find word with maximum vowel"

length=len(sample_string)
count=0
max_count=0
word=""
max_word=""

for i in range(length):
    if(sample_string[i].isspace()):
        if(count>max_count):
            max_count=count
            max_word=word

    count=0
    word=""
elif(sample_string[i]=='a' or sample_string[i]=='e' or
     sample_string[i]=='i' or sample_string[i]=='o' or 
         sample_string[i]=='u'):
        count=count+1
    word=word+sample_string[i]
print(max_word)
```